# Is a home directory folder created automatically for a local user when it is created

Tags: windows, user-accounts, home-directory

I am creating a new local user account using local users and groups in a windows machine.So will the home directory for the same user be created during the user creation in C:\Users folder or will it be created when the user first logs on to the machine?

Comment: Log in as a different user first and find out!

Comment: User profiles are only created when the user logs in.  I'm not sure whether `LoadUserProfile` will create a profile if one does not exist.